# How to load 2nd partial based on "Name" value from 1st partial in parent View?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to load _partialB based on `Name` value from _partialA. The `Name` is button in my scenario.

I am getting following error:

> Uncaught Error: can't load XRegExp twice in the same frame

Controller

```
 public ActionResult ABC(string name="")
        {
            SDetails sDetails=new SDetails();        
            var model = new ClsA();
            if(name=="")
            {
             name = sDetails.Rst().FirstOrDefault().Name;    
             model.firsts = sDetails.Rst();                    
             model.seconds = sDetails.Rs(name); 
            }
            else
            {
            model.firsts = sDetails.Rst();                    
             model.seconds = sDetails.Rs(name); 
            }

            return View(model);

         }
```

View

```
 @model Aplication.Models.ABC.ClsA 

<div id=myA>
 @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PartialA", Model.firsts); }
</div>
<div id=myB>
 @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PartialB", Model.seconds);} 
</div>
```

_PartialA

```
@model  IEnumerable<Aplication.Models.ABC.first>

    <table>
        <tr>
           <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Name)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Address)</th>            
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                 <button class="link" type="button" data- 
                    name="@item.name">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </button>

                </td>
                <td>                   
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)                    
                </td>                

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Script

```
$('#myA').on('click', '.link', function () {
            debugger;
          var name= $(this).data("name");
          var url = '@Url.Action("ABC", "ABC")?name=' + name;
          $('#myB').load(url);
        });
```

Comment: You need a separate method that just returns your `_PartialB.cshtml` partial, not the full view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, how to do that. please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a separate method that returns just your `_PartialB.cshtml`

```
public PartialViewResult PartialB(string name)
{
    List<first> model = sDetails.Rs(name);
    return PartialView("_PartialB", model);
}
```

and modify your script to

```
$('#myA').on('click', '.link', function () {
    var name= $(this).data("name");
    var url = '@Url.Action("PartialB")'; // assumes its in the same controller
    $('#myB').load(url, { name: name });
});
```