# Can we return PartialView and View in the same ActionResult in mVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to return both PartialView and View in the same ActionResult. What I want is that if `(model.spartial.Count` is equal to `0` then return the main View `ABC` else return the `_Partial`.

Note: JQuery code is updated.
Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is of type 'Ap.Models.ABC.ClsS', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[Ap.Models.ABC.SectionPartial]'

Please suggest me where I am going wrong.

Model

```
  public class ClsS
    {    
        public string MM { get; set; } //dropdown
        public string CC { get; set; } //dropdown

        public List<SectionPartial> sectionPartial { get; set; } 
    }

    public class SectionPartial
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Partial(string cc, string mm)
    {
        Details details = new Details();
        var model = new ClsS();

        model.spartial = details.spartialS(cc, mm);
        if (model.spartial.Count > 0)
        {
            return PartialView("_Partial", model);
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("_Partial", model);
        }
    }
```

_Partial

```
@model Ap.Models.ABC.ClsS

 @{ 
  Html.RenderPartial("_Section", Model.sectionPartial);
 }
```

JQuery
`'#CC,#MM'` is dropdownlist and `'#Rial'` is the `<div>` where I am displaying this partial.

```
$('#CC,#MM').change(function () {
  var url = '@Url.Action("partial", "ABC")'
  $('#Rial').load(url, { cc: $('#CC').val(),mm: $('#MM').val() })
});
```

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here to diagnose.  `XRegExp` is not mentioned anywhere in your code or description.

Comment: @SamAxe Sounds similar problem like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50233609/how-to-load-2nd-partial-based-on-name-value-from-1st-partial-in-parent-view. Because the request come from jQuery AJAX call, `return View()` certainly can't be used with `@Html.RenderPartial()` helper (the action should just return partial view).

Comment: @SamAxe, I updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Returning a full view in your ajax call does not really make sense - you would not want to repeat the layout, css, scripts etc. Its not really clear what you want to achieve with this. Your `else` block should also be returning a partial view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I want to return the partial view. But if the count is `0` then want to return the partial view with no data.

Comment: So why not `return PartialView("_Partial", new ClsS());`? (and I assume the error is related to that fact that your `ABC.cshtml` view is using [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) and therefore its loaded twice)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, If I return the way you have shown here, I am getting following error `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Ap.Models.ABC.ClsS', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Ap.Models.ABC.SectionPartial]'.'`

Comment: @User9895 Then you should pass `SectionPartial` as model argument instead of `ClsS` in `return PartialView(...)`. Not sure how to convert into `SectionPartial` because no part in your code mentions that.

Comment: To understand that error, read [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ). You have not shown what the models are or what the views are so we cannot help

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have updated question with modal and partial. Please have a look.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, I have updated the question with modal and partial view. Please guide me.

Comment: Then you would not be getting the error you claim if you have used `return PartialView("_Partial", new ClsS());` since the model is `@model ClsS`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I did the same as you suggested but still the error persist.

Comment: If you had read the Q/A I linked to you would know why :)  - it is now because `sectionPartial` is `null` so `Html.RenderPartial("_Section", Model.sectionPartial);` is passing `ClsS` to your `_Section.cshtml` partial which expects a IEnumerable<SectionPartial>` model

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171040/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user9895).